# Flutter Push vs. State-related views

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There are two ways to change what a user sees on display: I can push to another page or I can change the state of my stateful widget and rebuild it. Can you tell me, which way is best practice? (And if it depends - what I guess - on what?)

Pushing:

```
class Pushing extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage())),)
  ),
);
}
}
```

Using States

```
class UsingStates extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State createState() => new _UsingStatesState();
}

class _UsingStatesState extends State<UsingStates> {
 bool isPageTwo;

 @override
 void initState() {
  isPageTwo = false;
  super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: isPageTwo ? Center(child: Text('Page two')) : Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      isPageTwo = true;
    });
  })),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the answer is: It depends.

### When to use `Navigator`:

Routes pushed with the navigator are in a way equivalent to...

- `Activity` and `Fragment` in Android
- A route in Angular or React
- A html file of a classic web page

You would use the `Navigator` to switch between logically separate parts of your app. Think of a StackOverflow app that comes with different pages, e.g. "Question List", "Question Detail", "Ask Question" form and "User Profile".

`Navigator` takes care of back navigation (hardware back button on android phones + back arrow in `AppBar`)

Note that a route does not have to overlay the full screen. `showDialog` also uses `Navigator.push()` internally (that's why you use `Navigator.pop()` to dismiss a dialog.

Similar to `startActivityForResult` on Android, a route can also return a result when `pop` is called. Think of a dialog that lets you pick a date.

### When to use `State`:

Use `State` when the screens are a logical unit, e.g.:

- When you load a list of items from a server, you would have 4 different states:

  - Loading
  - "An error occured..."
  - Placeholder displayed when the list is empty
  - The `ListView`
- A form with multiple steps
- A screen with multiple tabs (in this case the navigations is handled by the tab bar)
- A "Please wait" overlay that blocks the screen while a `POST` request is sent to the server

---

After all `Navigator` is also a `StatefulWidget` that keeps track of the route history. Stateful widgets are a fundamental building block of Flutter. When your app is really complex and `Navigator` does not fit your needs, you can always create your own `StatefulWidget` for full control.

It always helps to look at Flutter's source code (CTRL + B in Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: new Page1(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
}
}
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
Page1({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
final String title;

@override
Page1State createState() => new Page1State();
}
class Page1State extends State<Page1> {
StreamController<int> streamController = new StreamController<int>();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new RaisedButton(child: new Text("This is Page 1, Press here to go to page 2"),onPressed:()=>streamController.add(2) ,),
  ),
);
}
@override
void initState() {
streamController.stream.listen((intValue){
  print("Page 1 stream : "+intValue.toString());
  if(intValue==2){
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Page2(title: "Page 2",)));
  }
});
super.initState();
}
@override
void dispose() {
streamController.close();
super.dispose();
}
}
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
Page2({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
final String title;
@override
Page2State createState() => new Page2State();
}
class Page2State extends State<Page2> {
StreamController<int> streamController = new StreamController<int>();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new RaisedButton(child: new Text("This is Page 2, Press here to go to page 2"),onPressed:()=> streamController.add(1),),
  ),
 );
 }
 @override
 void initState() {
 streamController.stream.listen((intValue){
  print("Page 2 stream : "+intValue.toString());
  if(intValue==1){
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Page1(title: "Page 1",)));
  }
  });
  super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
   streamController.close();
  super.dispose();
  }
  }
```

Sorry for bad formatting. You can run this code without any dependencies. Hope it helped