# Is Flutter Navigator necessary / important or are animations and state changes sufficient when appropriate

Tags: flutter, navigator, animatedcrossfade

In development we have found Flutter Navigator to be limiting to what we want to achieve. It seems very much set up for a conventional route structure however many of our user actions involve state changes that modify the existing screen rather than push a new page on top.

We have achieved this using a combination of customised CrossFaders and AnimatedSwitches with Provider handing the state management. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: tried nested `Navigator`s? something like [that](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/effects/nested-nav)

Comment: Part of this is helpful but essentially our transition is far more complicated retaining a number of elements from the previous page. We can achieve precisely what we want with a state change, its whether we should be using Navigator instead and if so how to achieve this kind of thing with Navigator.

Comment: This questions has been better asked here with a helpful explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811897/flutter-push-vs-state-related-views

Comment: you can still use [heroes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) in nested navigator, one minute intro vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be9UH1kXFDw

Comment: @pskink It has it's place but not for this example. Thanks for your help, R